# React Native Gesture Handler Full Swipe functionality where one button overtakes the other when swiped beyond certain threshold

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am implementing swipe to Delete Functionality in my App which works similar to Gmail and is built using react native.
In the app I am rendering various messages inside FlatList, Now i want to add:

1. Swipe functionality in that in such a way that if user tries to swipe the message card from the right side then till a certain threshold limit, two buttons should appear which are Save and Delete.
2. Now if user pushes the message card beyond certain threshold than Delete Button should overtake the Save button.

**As of now, First requirement is working fine but i am not able to achieve the second requirement i.e Delete button overtaking save button when pushed beyond certain threshold.**

I need to use *react-native-gesture-handler library only*.
I am referring to the react-native-gesture-handler GitHub repo example: [Example](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/main/example/src/showcase/swipeable/AppleStyleSwipeableRow.tsx)

Attaching the requirement image for reference.
[Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9puE.png)

Can anyone please help regarding how to achieve the desired effect.

- I need to use react-native-gesture-handler library.
- I referred the library documentation and the Github CodeBase but not able to find any solution regarding this.